# Drawing efficiently from independent Normal Inverse Wishart distributions

Tags: bayesian, sampling, matlab, inverse-wishart

I need to take **independent** draws from *Normal Inverse Wishart* distributions with different parameters. In practise I want to draw:

$x_i|\Sigma_i \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_i, \Sigma_i \otimes \Psi_i )$
$\Sigma_i \sim IW(S_i, v)$,

for $i = 1 , \ldots, T$

where $\Sigma_i$ is $N \times N$ and $x_i$ is $k \times 1$.
The parameter of the degrees of freedom of the *Inverse Wishart* is the same for all the distributions.

Right now, I am doing the draws from the *Normal Inverse Wishart* distributions one by one, and looping over T. I am using this Matlab code:

```
    for i = 1:T
      z = chol(inv(S{i})'*randn(N,v);   
      sig_sim = inv(z*z');
      vc = kron(sig_sim,Psi{i}); 
      [cf,pp] =chol(vc);
      x_sim  = mu{i} + cf'*randn(N*k,1); 
    end
```

Is there a way to avoid the loop over T and draw all the T *Normal Inverse Wishart* **jointly** (in a sigle step), since they are independent?

I am not asking how to take the draw from the marginal distribution of $x$. The question is not related in any way to that. I want to understand how to take a draw for $\Sigma_{1:T}$ and $x_{1:T}$ without looping over i.

Comment: you should read carefully the questions before closing them!

Comment: If you are still interested, you can edit the post to explain why the proposed dup do not answer your Q. It will then enter a queue for reopening!